# How to open more than one CSV file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am having real trouble opening several CSV files. I have one per participant and have managed to average the conditions for one, but instead of simply doing this 13 times and changing the file for each participant surely there is a quicker way? I have attempted using the glob function but it just does not seem to work.

```
f = csv.DictReader(open('path.csv', 'r'))

rts = {}

for a in f:
    condname = a['cond']
    rt = float(a['reactiontime'])

    list
    if not rts.has_key( condname ):
        rts[ condname ] = []


    rts[ condname ].append(rt)


for cond in rts.keys():
    data = np.array(rts[cond])
    m = data.mean()
    print("%s: Mean: %.3f   
    (cond, m))
```

Comment: Are the csv files in the same folder/directory? Are they the only files in the folder whose extensions are '.csv'?

Comment: Yeah all my csv files are in a folder together but when I use glob it says error and that the directory does not exist and there the only files in the folder and all end .csv

Comment: Can you do import os and check os.listdir() to check if you are in the correct directory?

Comment: What's the full name of the directory? (I should have asked before!)

Answer (score 1):

If your files are in the current folder, you can do:

```
import glob
csv_files = glob.glob('/Users/Username/Documents/*.csv')
```

And if your files are in current folder and sub-folders you can do something like this:

```
csv_files = glob.glob('/Users/Username/Documents/**/*.csv', recursive=True)
```

It will create a list of csv files which you can iter:

```
for file in csv_files:
  with open(file, 'r') as csvfile:
        file_reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
            ... # Do something with csvfile
```